# Smart Contract events

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, whisper

I am developing a Dapp that contains a notification between two Users. 
for example :

- User 1 (Student): send a transaction that contains data to be
  confirmed.
- User 2 (Professor):  receive a notification to validate  the student
  data.
- User 1 (Student): receive a notification about the    professor
  answer.

is't possible to implement this use case using smart contract events? 
I took a look to web3.shh but it seems like it miss documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can doing that by create your event in your Smart Contract like :

```
event StudentData(address indexed _professorAddr, string indexed _studentData)
```

Then, using web3 api you can watch/listen for this events by filtering on the professor address by exemple, and trigger any action, like a notification, when the event realise

See [documentation](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html?highlight=events) about events listening.

Comment: thnks for your quick answer. but how much time can  an event live? let's say the professor will open the app after 3 week of the student submission ?

Comment: According Solidity Documentation about events, it seems that events logs are stored in the blockchain, so the events are keep alive a long time that blockchain is alive I think. So in your case, when the professor open the Dapp the watch for event function start to listen from the first block to latest one and show you all of them.

Comment: Quoting the Solidity docs: "These logs are associated with the address of the contract, are incorporated into the blockchain, and stay there as long as a block is accessible (forever as of now, but this might change with Serenity)".